# Using Input Number to Update Number of Paragraphs Displayed - HTML Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to use a input number type to update how many times a particular amount of content is added to the page. In the example I'm doing it with a `p` tag but in my main model I'm using it on a larger scale with multiple divs. However, I can't seem to be able to get this to work. If someone can see where I'm going wrong that would be very helpful.

```js
function updatePage() {
  var i = document.getElementById("numerInput").value;
  document.getElementById("content").innerHTML =
    while (i > 1) {
      "<p>Content<p/><br>";
      i--;
    };
}
```

```html
<input type="number" value="1" id="numberInput">
<br>
<input type="button" value="Update" onclick="updatePage()">
<div id="content">
  <p>Content
    <p>
      <br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you have quite a few problems that need addressing:

You are setting the `.innerHTML` to a `while` loop, which is invalid because a loop doesn't have a return value. And, inside your loop, you just have a string of HTML. It isn't being returned or assigned to anything, so nothing will happen with it.

You've also mis-spelled the `id` of your `input`:

```
document.getElementById("numerInput")
```

Also, don't use inline HTML event attributes (i.e. `onclick`) as **[there are many reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43459890/javascript-function-doesnt-work-when-link-is-clicked/43459991#43459991)** not to use this 20+ year old antiquated technique that just will not die. Separate all your JavaScript work from your HTML.

Lastly, your HTML is invalid:

```
"<p>Content<p/><br>"
```

Should be:

```
"<p>Content</p>"
```

Notice that in addition to fixing the syntax for the closing `p`, the `<br>` has been removed. Don't use `<br>` simply to add spacing to a document - do that with CSS. `<br>` should be used only to insert a line feed into some content because that content should be broken up, but not into new sections.

---

Now, to solve your overall issue, what you should do is set the `.innerHTML` to the return value from a function or, more simply just the end result of what the loop creates as I'm showing below.

```js
// Get DOM references just once in JavaScript
let input = document.getElementById("numberInput");
let btn = document.querySelector("input[type='button']");

// Set up event handlers in JavaScript, not HTML with standards-based code:
btn.addEventListener("click", updatePage);

function updatePage() {
  var output = ""; // Will hold result
  
  // Instead of a while loop, just a for loop that counts to the value entered into the input
  for (var i = 0; i < input.value; i++) {
    // Don't modify the DOM more than necessary (especially in a loop) for performance reasons
    // Just build up a string with the desired output
    output += "<p>Content</p>"; // Concatenate more data
  };
  
  // After the string has been built, update the DOM
  document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = output;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" value="1" id="numberInput">
<br>
<input type="button" value="Update">
<div id="content">
  <p>Content</p>
</div>
```

And, if you truly do want the same string repeated the number of times that is entered into the `input`, then this can be a lot simpler with `string.repeat()`.

```js
// Get DOM references just once in JavaScript
let input = document.getElementById("numberInput");
let btn = document.querySelector("input[type='button']");

// Set up event handlers in JavaScript, not HTML with standards-based code:
btn.addEventListener("click", updatePage);

function updatePage() {
  // Just use string.repeat()
  document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = "<p>Content</p>".repeat(input.value);
}
```

```html
<input type="number" value="1" id="numberInput">
<br>
<input type="button" value="Update">
<div id="content">
  <p>Content</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As @ScottMarcus pointed out you had the following issues:

1. `While Loops` do not need a `;` at the end of `while(args) {}`
2. Your `.innerHTML` code was in the wrong place
3. You had a typo in `getElementById("numerInput")` which I changed to `getElementById("numberInput")`

**Code**

---

```js
  function updatePage() {
    // Get input value
    var numberInput = document.getElementById("numberInput").value;

    // Will be used to store all <p> contents
    var template = "";

    while (numberInput > 0) {
      // Add all contents into template
      template += "<p>Content<p/><br>";

      numberInput--;
    }
    // Append upon clicking
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = template;
  }
```

```html
<input type="number" value="1" id="numberInput">
<br>
<input type="button" value="Update" onclick="updatePage()">
<div id="content">
</div>
```

Comment: Please don't post code to 3rd party sites as those links can die over time. Just edit your answer and place your executable code in a "code snippet" and then it will be able to be run right here.

Comment: Sure. Will change it now.